# How to create an AudioBuffer from a Blob?

Tags: blob, web-audio-api, audiobuffer, web-mediarecorder

I have an audio file/blob that has been created using the `MediaRecorder` api:

```
let recorder = new MediaRecorder(this.stream)
let data = [];
recorder.ondataavailable = event => data.push(event.data);
```

and then later when the recording is finished:

```
let superBlob = new Blob(data, { type: "video/webm" });
```

How can I use this blob to create an `AudioBuffer`? I need to either :

- Transform the `Blob` object into an `ArrayBuffer` which I could use with `AudioContext.decodeAudioData` (returns an `AudioBuffer`) or
- Transform the `Blob` object into an `Float32Array`, where I could copy it into the `AudioBuffer` with `AudioBuffer.copyToChannel()`

Any tips on how to achieve that are appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To convert a `Blob` object to an `ArrayBuffer`, use `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer`.

```
let fileReader = new FileReader();
let arrayBuffer;

fileReader.onloadend = () => {
    arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;
}

fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(superBlob);
```

Comment: I am using this in my implementation but the `fileReader.result` always returns an empty `ArrayBuffer` - do you know what could be happening? Further details can be found in [this question that I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43572151/web-audio-blob-to-arraybuffer-converstion-results-in-empty-arraybuffer-array)

Comment: Are you sure you are checking `fileReader.result` in the `onloadend` event?

Comment: Yea I've managed to get it working, it was a trivial mistake on my end so sorry about that. Thanks a lot for posting this answer though, it has been very helpful!

Comment: not sure how trivial the mistake was.  I found that you can't access the resulting array buffer directly.  I used data = new Uint8Array(reader.result);

Comment: As stated by PAT-O-MATION, this returns an arrayBuffer, not audioBuffer

Answer (score 12):

The accepted answer is great but only gives an array buffer which is not an audio buffer. You need to use the audio context to convert the array buffer into an audio buffer.

```
const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const fileReader = new FileReader();

// Set up file reader on loaded end event
fileReader.onloadend = () => {

    const arrayBuffer = fileReader.result as ArrayBuffer

    // Convert array buffer into audio buffer
    audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, (audioBuffer) => {
    
      // Do something with audioBuffer
      console.log(audioBuffer)
    
    })
      
}

//Load blob
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob)
```

I wish the answer had included an example using `decodeAudioData`. I had to find it somewhere else and I thought since this is the top search for "Blob to Audio Buffer" I would add some helpful information for the next person that comes down this rabbit hole.

Comment: do not use this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66450267/webaudioapi-decodeaudiodata-giving-null-error-on-ios-14-safari, `decodeAudioData` only works with file

Answer (score 6):

All the answers are true. However, in the modern web browsers like Chrome 76 and Firefox 69, there is a much simpler way: using `Blob.arrayBuffer()`

Since `Blob.arrayBuffer()` returns a Promise, you can do either

```js
superBlob.arrayBuffer().then(arrayBuffer => {
  // Do something with arrayBuffer
});
```

or

```js
async function doSomethingWithAudioBuffer(blob) {
  var arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
  // Do something with arrayBuffer;
}
```

Comment: Just tried that, and what you get back is an arrayBuffer, not an audioBuffer

Comment: @Will59 Would you read the question more carefully? The questioner is aware of how to convert an ArrayBuffer into an AudioBuffer. The question isn't about getting an AudioBuffer from a Blob.

Comment: Read your code more carefully then... Don't write 'audioBuffer' where you get in fact an arrayBuffer.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 3):

A simplified version using an async function:

```
async function blobToAudioBuffer(audioContext, blob) {
  const arrayBuffer = await blob.arrayBuffer();
  return await audioContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
}
```

I put `audioContext` as a param, because I recommend reusing instances.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69452545/safari-15-fails-to-decode-audio-data-that-previous-versions-decoded-without-prob

Answer (score 2):

Both Answers are true, there are some minor changes. This is the function I finally used:

```
function convertBlobToAudioBuffer(myBlob) {

  const audioContext = new AudioContext();
  const fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onloadend = () => {

    let myArrayBuffer = fileReader.result;

    audioContext.decodeAudioData(myArrayBuffer, (audioBuffer) => {

      // Do something with audioBuffer

    });
  };

  //Load blob
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(myBlob);
}
```