# Safari 15 fails to decode audio data that previous versions decoded without problems

Tags: javascript, safari, audiocontext

I'm using AudioContext to load an .mp3 file for a game. It used to work fine, but after Safari 15 came out I'm getting reports from people where the sound will not play. The sound used to work fine for them before they upgraded their browser.

On my own Safari 15 it works fine, but for some people the call `audioContext.decodeAudioData` is failing, they just get `EncodingError: Decoding failed` and no extra information. I tried using .aac files instead of .mp3 but the same thing happens.

Hard to figure this out since I can't reproduce it myself. Any ideas?

Comment: Having the exact same issue myself. Could not reproduce locally, could not figure out any possible reason for it beyond a new browser bug which I could do nothing about. Ended up catching failed decodeAudioData calls and falling back to a Wasm-backed decoding library (from [wasm-audio-decoders](https://github.com/eshaz/wasm-audio-decoders)). Shaking my fists at Apple that I have to do this, but it seems to work like a charm.

Comment: Note, I actually took the opportunity to switch to Opus audio, which Safari doesn't natively support anyway. [My fork of wasm-audio-decoders](https://github.com/strummachine/wasm-audio-decoders) includes my modifications to do the decoding in a Web Worker, which prevents blocking the main thread (just like decodeAudioData runs in a separate thread).

Comment: Also, in case it's a useful data point, my Sentry logs suggested that this issue was hitting about 20% of Safari 15 users.

Comment: @LukeAbbott Thanks, that's very helpful! And the 20% sounds about right, I was getting quite a few messages about this, but nowhere near as many as I'd expect if this was affecting everyone. What makes this extra annoying is that none of the 3 devices I have with Safari 15 are affected, so it's hard to test any workarounds. But I'll look into the wasm-audio-decoder!

Comment: Cool! And, same: tested on two M1 Macs and two x86 Macs, and of course it worked flawlessly on them.

Comment: Ok, I've almost got this working, but I'm decoding a lot of ~1 second sounds and they don't sound quite right, but I still hear something. My code is something like :
`let {channelData, samplesDecoded, sampleRate} = this.decoder.decode(new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer));
let buffer = this.audioContext.createBuffer(2, samplesDecoded, sampleRate);
buffer.copyToChannel(channelData[0], 0);
buffer.copyToChannel(channelData[1], 1);`

Sometimes creating a buffer fails, it kinda seems like the decoder keeps some internal state between files. How are you using it?

Comment: I've tested on 4 machines with Safari 15. Two machines have the decoding issue, two don't. 
The two that do are running macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina). 
The two that don't are running macOS 11+ (BigSur). 
Of course with N=4 this is very inconclusive, but it might be a hint. Anyone else seeing a correlation between macOS version and the issue on their machines?

Comment: @EinarEgilsson since you mentioned that you are decoding a lot of files, do you think the problem could be related to this bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=227636?

Comment: @Reinier I have at least one affected user on Big Sur, so I don't think that's it.

Comment: @EinarEgilsson I'm also decoding lots of 1-3 second files. In my web worker, I'm having to "free" the decoder after every file, maybe that's it; see [here](https://github.com/strummachine/wasm-audio-decoders/blob/58c9861da7f997760734c65029c515b685cdffaa/src/ogg-opus-decoder/src/emscripten-post.js#L236). Otherwise I'm using copyToChannel just like you, though I'm falling back to `getChannelData` for Safari < 14.1.

Comment: @chrisguttandin I don't think that bug is related because a) it fails to decode even one file, and b) it doesn't crash, it simply fails.

Comment: Based on Sentry logs, we are seeing this issue with approximately 5% of our Safari 15 users. All are on 10.15.7.

Comment: Filed here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=231872

Answer (score 4):

There is a sandbox regression affecting Safari 15 with macOS Catalina 10.15.  It blocks decoding of audio with web audio

Comment: Ok, probably easiest to just wait this one out, any ideas when they plan to release an update that fixes this?

Comment: Have they fixed this yet? How they didn't fast-track a hotfix is beyond me.

Comment: I don’t have the issue on Safari 15.2 (16612.3.6.1.8, 16612) under BigSur, but I have it on STP 137 (Safari 15.4, WebKit 16613.1.11.8), also BigSur.

Comment: A year later and still no fix for MacOS 10.15.  Broken in Safari 16 as well. Just need people to upgrade or switch browsers.