# Decoding failed for Safari browser while using audioContext.decodeAudioData

Tags: websocket, safari, vuejs3, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

I have a Vue JS application in which I am playing an audio stream coming from a Websocket connection. The audio stream is coming continuously in chunks so I have implemented a logic to play the incoming chunks in a queue. Everything works great in Chrome browser but unfortunately it breaks in Safari. I did a lot of research on this but I am not able to find any solution to this problem.

Here is my Code

```
vm.socket = new WebSocket('wss://my_website.com');

//required to receive data in array buffer type. If not mentioned I get Blob's
vm.socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer'


vm.socket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {


    const audioData = new Uint8Array(event.data);

    this.audioQueue.push(audioData);
    if (!this.isPlaying) {
        this.playNextChunk();
    }

});

//Main method which is responsible to process incoming audio chunks
async playNextChunk() {

    if (this.audioQueue.length === 0) {
        this.isPlaying = false;
        return;
    }

    this.isPlaying = true;
    const audioData = this.audioQueue.shift();

    try {
        //decode audio data (This fails randomly in between in Safari browser)
        const audioBuffer = this.audioContext.decodeAudioData(audioData.buffer);
        const source = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = audioBuffer;
        source.connect(this.audioContext.destination);
        source.onended = this.playNextChunk;
        source.start();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error decoding audio data', error);
    }

}
```

Here is a screenshot of console logs
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safari 15 fails to decode audio data that previous versions decoded without problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69452545/safari-15-fails-to-decode-audio-data-that-previous-versions-decoded-without-prob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to decode the audio data on Safari without any issue after using audio-decode library https://www.npmjs.com/package/audio-decode

```
const playNextChunk = async () => {
    // Get the current value of the audioQueue from a ref
    const audioQueue = audioQueueRef.current;

    // Log the current value of audioQueue
    console.log("audioQueue in pnc", audioQueue);

    // Check if there are items in the audioQueue
    if (audioQueue.length > 0) {
      console.log("Audio queue length is: " + audioQueue.length)
      // If there are items, remove the first item from the queue
      const audioBuffer = audioQueue.shift();

      // Check if the audioBuffer exists
      if (audioBuffer) {
        // If it exists, play the audio buffer asynchronously
        await playAudio(audioBuffer);
      }
    } else {
      // If there are no chunks remaining in the audio queue:
      console.log("NO CHUNKS REMAINING IN THE AUDIO QUEUE")

      // Clear the audioQueue by assigning an empty array to it
      audioQueueRef.current = [];
    }
  };

  const playAudio = async (
    audio: Uint8Array,
    isForWelcomeMsg: boolean = false
  ) => {
    if (audio && audioContextRef?.current) {
      try {
        console.log("decoders.mp3()");
        await decoders.mp3(); // load & compile decoder []
        console.log("decoders.mp3(audioData)");

        const audioData = await decoders.mp3(audio); // decode
        console.log("DECODING COMPLETE");

        console.log("playing started");

        if (audioSourceRef.current) {
          audioSourceRef.current.disconnect(audioContextRef.current.destination);
          audioSourceRef.current.stop()
          audioSourceRef.current = null
        }

        audioSourceRef.current = audioContextRef.current.createBufferSource();
        audioSourceRef.current.buffer = audioData;
        audioSourceRef.current.connect(audioContextRef.current.destination);
        audioSourceRef.current.start(0);

        audioSourceRef.current.onended = async () => {
          console.log("Completed playing a CHUNK"); 
          await playNextChunk();
        };

      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error while audio decode");
      }
    } else {
      //do cleanup
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 15, Safari does not support decodeAudioData anymore for anything but WAV files.